# Error when running sudo snap revert through SSH using Fabric under Jenkins

Tags: python, ubuntu, jenkins, fabric, snapcraft

I am trying to use Fabric to run a `snap revert` command in a remote Ubuntu 18.14 machine through ssh. The command works when I run it manually, but it fails when I try to run it through Jenkins.

Here is the code I use:

```
from fabric import Config, Connection
connection = Connection(
    node_ip,
    config=Config(overrides={"sudo": {"password": sudo_pass}}),
    user=user,
    connect_kwargs={"password": sudo_pass},
)
connection.sudo("snap revert mysnap-app")
```

The error I see is this:

```
...
raise ThreadException(thread_exceptions)
invoke.exceptions.ThreadException: 
Saw 1 exceptions within threads (OSError):

hread args: {'kwargs': {'buffer_': ['[sudo] password: \n'],
            'hide': False,
            'output': <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>},
 'target': <bound method Runner.handle_stderr of <fabric.runners.Remote object at 0x10fb06a00>>}

Traceback (most recent call last):
...
File "/.../site-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 1198, in _send
    raise socket.error("Socket is closed")

OSError: Socket is closed
```

I tried unsetting the pty with `pty=False` with same results. This is consistent: it works when run manually on the same machine that I run the Jenkins Agent, but always fails when is run by the Jenkins Agent.

Any Idea on how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that this was only related to Fabric and sudo. The solution is to add `pty=True` which at the time I thought it was the default.